# CASE WHEN inside a COUNT, will returning 0 be counted?

Tags: mysql

I want to get a percentage of lines having a specific feature. For that I use the following query:

```
select 
count(distinct case when a.has_feature="Y" then p.id else 0 end)*100/count(distinct p.id)
FROM products p
JOIN a on a.id=p.id
WHERE 1
```

This query is simplified, but the goal is to get this percentage in only one query, and the test on `a.has_feature="Y"` cannot be in the `WHERE` clauses as I also need the products which do not have the feature.

My question is about the first count.
`case when` will return `p.id` or 0. Is 0 counted or should I use `null` or something else so that when it hasn't the feature it is not counted ?

Comment: Simply try it out! To answer your question, 0 will count, NULL won't.

Comment: I will not try it out before being sure because it will run several hours but thanks for explaining count of 0 and null

Comment: You don't have to run this particular query. A simple test query would do either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will count. 0 is a valid value and will be counted. Null won't be counted.